# Brother HL-2270DW stopped printing

Tags: 12.04, usb, printing, brother

Not sure why my printer suddenly stopped printing.  I have a `Brother HL-2270DW` connected via USB.

The `/var/log/syslog` show the the following when I unplug and replug the USB cord in.  The only thing that really sticks out to me is: `udev-configure-printer: failed to claim interface`

```
Mar 31 19:21:54 spaceship kernel: [  592.888013] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1"
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship kernel: [  593.022311] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x0042
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: Device vendor/product is 04F9:0042
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usb/lp0
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: failed to claim interface
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1
Mar 31 19:21:55 spaceship udev-configure-printer: MFG:Brother MDL:HL-2270DW series SERN:- serial:E2N539264
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship kernel: [  594.102843] usblp0: removed
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usb/lp0
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship kernel: [  594.108433] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x0042
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: URI contains USB serial number
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://Brother/HL-2270DW%20series?serial=E2N539264
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: Consider also queues with "/usb/lp0" or "/usblp0" in their URIs as matching
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: usb://Brother/HL-2270DW%20series?serial=E2N539264, normalized: brother hl 2270dw series serial e2n539264
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://Brother/HL-2270DW%20series?serial=E2N539264, normalized: brother hl 2270dw series serial e2n539264
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/HL2270DW has matching device URI
Mar 31 19:21:56 spaceship udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/HL2270DW
```

lsusb sees the printer:

```
root@spaceship:/var/spool/cups# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f9:0042 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c313 Logitech, Inc. Internet 350 Keyboard
```

And the printer is still visible via CUPS by going to: `http://localhost:631/`

But regardless no jobs actually come out.  What else can I check on this sucker?

Comment: I have a printer of the same model and I get the same `failed to claim interface` message in the syslog when I connect my printer, which prints fine. So I don't think that message indicates a problem.

Comment: Bummer, Im going to try and reinstall the drivers, think I can just lay them over the ones already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running [this script](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00104) from the Brothers Website and it corrected the issue.

After I ran the script it auto-added a second printer to the one I already had installed, so I deleted the new printer and the one I originally configured started to work again.

Not sure what broke it, probably and update somewhere but Im back in business.

Comment: As that link felt victim to link-rot: Do you still have that script? I've got a similar issue here, and would like to take a look at it.

Comment: @Izzy Try either of these URLs for the installer: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all  http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1.html?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&redirect=on

Comment: Ah, the "script" was just the installer? OK, good to know, thanks. Different printer here, so I'd need to take another URL then. But it might just have become obsolete in my case (will see that within the next days): the errors in my logs had a different cause (the fax driver was behind them, not liking his device URI; I've just deactivated that and the errors stopped). Now I need to see whether the printer starts behaving again, and not putting each job on pause initially :)

Comment: Im pretty sure it was an actual script that cleaned some stuff up and then downloaded and ran the installer, its been awhile so I cant remember exactly.  I'll see if I still have it saved at home but I doubt it.

Comment: Yes, sure. Must be the so-called "Driver Install Tool" you see in the downloads (after selecting "Linux (deb)" and pressing the "Search" button). AFAIR that's just a shell script (`install.sh`) which checks the requirements and then calls `dpkg` do install the packages.